# Is it correct to use "of" in this manner?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, repetition

For the following sentence:

> We request that they identify a faculty sponsor from the pertinent department to ensure awareness of activities of interest.

Would this be the proper way to use "of" in this case?  I feel that the phrasing is awkward when I read it aloud.

Comment: Yes, it's correct grammar-wise.

Comment: Nothing wrong with *of*, but it seems an awfully pompous way of making a simple point. Why not *Please could each department appoint someone to make everyone else aware of activities of interest*?

Answer (score 2):

Consider just the phrases "awareness of activities" and "activities of interest".

It should hopefully be clear when you isolate them like this, that in each case *of* is the appropriate way to link the nouns involved into a noun-phrase.

And hence that "awareness of activities of interest" is perfectly correct.

> I feel that the phrasing is awkward when I read it aloud.

Awkwardness is in the eye of the beholder, but I can see your point. The doubling of *of* and the relatively long words is not the most beautiful phrasing one will ever read. Still, none of those long words are egregiously used, and the double *of* is clear, so while it's not poetry, it's perfectly fine for a formal request.